# Pandas data frame for loop meaning of code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code I wrote where I wanted to take the percentage of the price of a vehicle based on their specific color. To do this, I found this one line of code to accomplish that goal. Even though it accomplishes my goal, I (as a new programmer) am having trouble understanding what it means in plain English. The first table is my original. The second is the result I got which is exactly what I wanted.  The line of code im focusing on is **cost = df[‘Price’][i]/df[df[‘Color’]==df.loc[i,’Color’]][‘Price’].sum()** . Can someone explain what this line means

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(‘Cars.xlsx’)

col = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
   cost = df[‘Price’][i]/df[df[‘Color’]==df.loc[i,’Color’]][‘Price’].sum()
   col.append(cost)

df[‘Cost Percentage per Color’] = col
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=‘Color’)

df_sorted.to_excel(‘Cars_New.xlsx, index=False)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have a look at `groupby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['Price'][i]` gets the price at the index i

`df[df['Color']==df.loc[i,'Color']]['price']` gets the price for each item that shares the color (`df['Color']`)  with the current color you are looking for (which is located with `df.loc[i,'Color']`). Essentially it is picking the price at each row that has a `Color` that matches the `Color` at the index you are looking at in each iteration of the loop. So `df[df['Color']==df.loc[i,'Color']]` gets the rows where the color matches the color at index i and `...['Price'].sum()` sums the price for each of those rows.

Then it divides the price of the current vehicle by the sum of the cost of all the vehicles of that color.